# Logins stop working when switching to wsgi with Flask, Flask login, mod-wsgi

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, flask-login

I have a flask webserver doing basic account authentication for users with flask-login. If I run the webserver myself account authentication works as expected. Upon using Apache and mod-wsgi to run the flask server, the current user session is dropped soon after authentication. So upon any refresh you are booted back to the login page. I believe my virtualhosts file is not set up correctly.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName testing.myApp.io
   # ProxyPreserveHost On
   # ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8888/
   # ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8888/
    LogLevel info

    WSGIDaemonProcess myApp user=myUser threads=1 home=/var/www/myApp/

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myApp/myApp.wsgi
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

     <Directory /var/www/myApp/app/>
        WSGIProcessGroup myApp

        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/myApp/app/static
    <Directory /var/www/myApp/app/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>


Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
#ServerAlias testing.myApp.io
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/testing.myApp.io/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/testing.myApp.io/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

My other concern is that somehow having multiple instances of flask login, the user is being authenticated by one and then not being recognized by another. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Some other relevant pieces from my code.
WSGI file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/myApp/")

from app import app as application
```

Views:

```
from app import app, lm
from flask import request, redirect, render_template, url_for, flash, json
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, login_required, current_user
from .forms import LoginForm, SignUpForm
from .user import User
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from urllib.parse import unquote
import os

UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "static" 
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


def flash_errors(form):
    for field, errors in form.errors.items():
        for error in errors:
            flash( error,category='error' )
            print ((getattr(form, field).label.text,error))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
        user = app.config['USERS_COLLECTION'].find_one({"_id": form.username.data})
        if user and User.validate_login(user['password'], form.password.data):
            user_obj = User(user['_id'])
            login_user(user_obj)
            flash("Logged in successfully!", category='success')
            return redirect(request.args.get("next") or url_for("write"))
        flash("Wrong username or password!", category='error')
        print("Bad Login")
    return render_template('login.html', title='login', form=form)

@app.route('/signUp', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signUp():
    form = SignUpForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            user = app.config['USERS_COLLECTION'].find_one({"_id": form.username.data})
            if user:
                flash("username already taken", category='error')
            else:
                pass_hash = generate_password_hash(form.password.data)
                uId = app.config['USERS_COLLECTION'].insert({"_id": form.username.data, "password": pass_hash, "data":{"posts":[]}})
                user_obj = User(uId)
                login_user(user_obj)
                flash("Logged in successfully!", category='success')
                return redirect(request.args.get("next") or url_for("write"))
        else:
            flash_errors(form)

    return render_template('signUp.html', title='Sign Up!', form=form)


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))


@app.route('/write', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def write():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # data = json.loads(unquote(request.query_string.decode().split('&')[0]))
        post = request.get_json()["post"]#data.get('post')
        print(post)

        current_user.write_post(post)
        return json.dumps({'success':True}), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'} 


    return render_template('write.html', posts=current_user.get_posts())

@app.route('/deleteAllPosts', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def deleteAllPosts():

    current_user.deleteAllPosts()
    return json.dumps({'success':True}), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'} 

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            print('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url, code=303)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            print('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url, code=303)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return json.dumps({'success':True}), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'} 
@app.route('/photos2/<name>')
def photos2(name):
    return redirect( url_for('photos2', filename=name))

@app.route('/settings', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def settings():
    return render_template('settings.html')



@lm.user_loader
def load_user(username):
    u = app.config['USERS_COLLECTION'].find_one({"_id": username})
    if not u:
        return None
    return User(u['_id'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed, turns out my Flask session was the issue, it was not persisting because the secret key was being randomly generated every time it was launched. I changed the secret key to a static variable and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I am using session for my web app and faced the same issue when i moved it to mod_wsgi. Although I already wasted a lot of time on this but I am sure your post saved me a lot of it!

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue, different solution...

I have two wsgi application on the same virtualhost.

I forgot to  define different wsgiprocessgroup for each application.